# how to Count the number of Payments (child) of opportunity(parent) for THIS_MONTH

Tags: apex, soql

```
 for(Opportunity o: [SELECT Id,First_Payment_Date__c,OwnerId,Owner.Name ,of_Payments_Made__c,First_Client_Payment_Collected_Date__c ,(Select Id,Opportunity__c,Due_Date__c FROM Payments__r)From Opportunity WHERE First_Payment_Date__c!=null]){
if(!oppMap.containsKey(o.OwnerId)){
                 oppMap.put(o.OwnerId,new List<Opportunity>());   
            }
            oppList.add(o);}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an aggregate query like:

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) numberOfPayments, Opportunity__c
    FROM Payments__c
    WHERE Due_Date__c = THIS_MONTH
    GROUP BY Opportunity__c
```

You can call this is Apex, and get back an AggregateResult array. You can access each result like:

```
for (AggregateResult result : [SELECT ...]) {
    Id oppId = (Id) result.get('Opportunity__c');
    Integer numberOfPaymentsThisMonth = Integer.valueOf(result.get('numberOfPayments'));

    // Do something with these details
}
```

See the [SOQL documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby.htm) for more details.

Comment: how can i send this integer numberOfPaymentsThisMonth  to my lightning component , am returning list of opp

Comment: Thi is not a ist of opportunities but is a list of aggregate results. Copy the details you need into data objects (instances of you own Apex class o inner class) and return the list. Sounds like you need to do some trailhead to understand wire and imperative calls to aura enabled methods.